# Class error, expected ; before ( token

Tags: c++, class, nested

I got error:

> expected ';' before '(' token.

Why is this happening? How can I resolve it?

```
#include <iostream>

class AB {
int n;
AB(int x) { n = x;}
};


class ED {

AB blee(1);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely being parsed wrong and failing:

```
AB blee(1);
```

If you are trying to initialize a data member of type `AB`, you cannot do it like that. In C++11 you can do it like this:

```
AB blee{1};
```

or

```
AB blee = 1;
```

Alternatively, you can do it in `ED`'s constructor(s). This works both in C++11 and C++03.

```
class ED {
  ED() : blee(1) {}
  AB blee;
};
```

Comment: if a write AB blee = 1 I get error: invalid in-class initialization of static data member of non-integral type `AB'

also if write

Comment: @user2085124 do you have C++11 support?

Comment: i am compiling in DevC++, not GCC, so i think so not

Comment: @user2085124 that doesn't answer my question (I don't know about DevC++), but it sounds like you don't have the required C++11 support. The last code sample works in plain old C++03 though.

Answer (score 3):

You must instantiate by the constructor through *member-initialization*:

```
class ED {
    ED() : blee(1) {}

    AB blee;
};
```

Comment: You only *must* do this if you don't have C++11.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do with your `AB blee(1);`? It's neither a function declaration nor a function call.

To call a function, you'd put it in the body of some member of `ED`, and leave off the `AB`, leaving just `blee(1);`.

To declare a function, you'd need to put a type (e.g., `int`) inside the parens: `AB blee(int);`

Comment: my goal was to achieve when i call in main function `ED object;` to make object.blee.n = 1